# Minimizing L1 distances using ortools

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, absolute-value

I'm trying to place rectangular boxes into a larger box. Some of these boxes are connected by wires. I want to minimize the L1 distance of these wires. This requires taking the absolute value of variables and ortools doesn't like that. According to the docs, `AddAbsEquality` should perhaps be used but there is no explanation on how.

Below is a MWE of what I want to accomplish:

```
from itertools import combinations
from ortools.sat.python.cp_model import *
from random import *

def place_boxes(width, height, boxes, connections):
    m = CpModel()

    # Non-overlapping boxes
    x1s = [m.NewIntVar(0, width, '') for _ in boxes]
    x2s = [m.NewIntVar(0, width, '') for _ in boxes]
    y1s = [m.NewIntVar(0, height, '') for _ in boxes]
    y2s = [m.NewIntVar(0, height, '') for _ in boxes]

    x_ints = [m.NewIntervalVar(x1, b[0], x2, '')
              for (x1, x2, b) in zip(x1s, x2s, boxes)]
    y_ints = [m.NewIntervalVar(y1, b[1], y2, '')
              for (y1, y2, b) in zip(y1s, y2s, boxes)]
    m.AddNoOverlap2D(x_ints, y_ints)

    # Minimize L1 distances
    distances = []
    for f, t in connections:
        # This doesnt work!
        distances.append(abs(x1s[f] - x1s[t]) + abs(y1s[f] - y1s[t]))
    m.Minimize(sum(distances))


    s = CpSolver()
    if s.Solve(m) in (OPTIMAL, FEASIBLE):
        locs = [(s.Value(x), s.Value(y), b[0], b[1])
                for (x, y, b) in zip(x1s, y1s, boxes)]
        print(locs)
        for f, t in connections:
            xd = abs(locs[f][0] - locs[t][0])
            yd = abs(locs[f][1] - locs[t][1])
            print(f, t, xd + yd)
    else:
        print('No solution found!')


def main():
    n_boxes = 10
    boxes = [(randint(1, 3), randint(1, 3)) for _ in range(n_boxes)]
    connections = sample(list(combinations(range(n_boxes), 2)), 10)
    print(connections)
    place_boxes(20, 10, boxes, connections)        
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

use `model.AddAbsEquality(target_var, var)`

See https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#CpModel.AddAbsEquality

Used here: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/zebra_sat.py#L96

```
  # to implement y = abs(a - b) with a and b in [0..10]
  diff = model.NewIntVar(-10, 10, 'diff')
  model.AddEquality(diff, a - b)
  model.AddAbsEquality(y, diff)
```

Comment: I don't understand how it works. Could you write an example for minimizing distance sums?